# Entity Framework Query multiple collections

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My context is marked with

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

I want to load selected related entities. Example like

```
context.Entry(catalog)
       .Collection(p => p.Products)
   .Query()
   .Where(p => p.VendorId == 1)
   .Load();
```

This works fine.

```
context.Entry(catalog)
       .Collection(p => p.Tags)
   .Query()
   .Where(p => p.TagId== 1)
   .Load();
```

This works fine too. But I assume this causes two separate Db calls. I want to make this in one call. How can I do that ? (I do not want to use .Include because it loads a huge list of another property values into the category object). Any ideas ?

***Update***

I want to load both Product and Tag at the same time without loading them separately as above.