# Entity Framework load multiple collections in one request

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

In basic I'm looking for the simplest way to get an associated collection of an entity in one request.

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
 {
   context.Users.Attach(user);
   context.Entry(user)
   .Collection(f => f.Followers)
   .Query()
   .Where(x => x.Whatever)
   //.Collection(r => r.Requests) doesn't work
   //.Collection(b => b.Blocks) doesn't work
   .Load();
 }
```

I'm aware that I could split these up into 3 different requests, but I'm wanting only one trip to the db.

Alternatively I was able to pull this off:

```
var user = context.Users
           .Include(f => f.Followers)
           .Include(r => r.Requests)
```

The problem with the approach above is I'm unable to filter the collections in the include with a .Where clause.

This question is very much:
[EF 6 filtering child collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079166/ef-6-filtering-child-collections)

As well as:
[Entity Framework Query multiple collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327250/entity-framework-query-multiple-collections)

Neither of which were able to be pulled off with one request, so I'm guessing its not possible?

Comment: If you want to filter the related entities in one round trip, then you will need to project your query with the expected result

Comment: Actually using a single SQL (db trip) to return multiple child collections like in the `Include` example is much more inefficient than using separate roundtrips because the returned result set must be a Cartesian product of all the child records with union-ed fields (most of  them being `null`). So even if you can make it somehow working, don't do it that way.

Comment: @octavioccl can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF in its base does not support that.

You can split it into 3 separate queries and use some external library to do it in single round trip, for example **Future Queries** of **EntityFramework.Extended** nuget library.